# How do caches work with servers?

Tags: caching, server

Can someone explain **how a cache works with servers** and such? I am a bit confused how they interact.

Answer (score 1):

Our browser establishes a TCP connection to the Web cache and sends an HTTP request for the object to the Web cache.
Web Cache has its own local storage, it checks whether it has that object, if it finds it, it returns the object to client browser as a response.
But if Web Cache doesn't find it, it establishes a TCP connection with origin server and sends a request to it. The origin server returns the object to the web cache as a response.
The client server sends the object to the client browser and saves its copy in its memory locally.
In this way, Cache Server acts both as a Client as well as a Server.
That's how Cache works with server.
 Hope it helps:)